# Windows 8 tablet and a mouse

Tags: windows

I need to buy a new computer or a tablet for school.

Some new tablet computers have a keyboard and mouse, some of them don't.

If I buy a tablet with Windows 8, will I be able to use a mouse?

Comment: I bought an µUSB to USB cable and here I can use a normal USB hub and connect Mouse/Keyboard/Ethernet Adapter/USB flash drives to my Toshiba encore 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the mouse and keyboard has Bluetooth capabilities.

Comment: USB will work too, if the tablet has a USB port (don't buy one without).